# How to find if any of the values in a range of variable contains a specific string

Tags: variables, sas, any

So I have a range of variables that were created by transposing the long-format data to wide-format. For example, result1-result13. Now I want to find if any of the results between 1-10 is 'positive'. Is there ANY shortcut function in SAS. I tried ANY function but it said it was unknown to SAS lol.

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, this is quite easy to do if you are in long format in SQL.

Comment: So result1-result13 are character variables?

Comment: Hi @Joe, any help if it was in long format?

Answer (score 1):

The [`whichc`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003122577.htm) function is probably what you're looking for.

```
found = whichc('positive', of result1-result13);
```

`whichc` tells you which of the arguments is the first to contain the first string, or 0 if none do.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, the 'found' variable returns the number of times 'positive' appears across the range of variables specified. this is helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not the number. The LOCATION of the first occurrence.  You can make it boolean (0/1) by making the right side of the assignment a logical expression like: `found=0<whichc('positive',of result1-result10);`